# Add Page Tab redirect to invalid location

Tags: facebook, tabs

When I've user Add Page Tab Dialog, I've passed redirect_uri like this

```
http://MYSITE/?r=c/action&token=123456789
```

when the dialog come back, it strips the token variable, so the url looks like

```
http://MYSITE/?r=c%2Faction&&tabs_added%5B176281002470701%5D=1#_=_
```

the token variable lost,

any body have any idea why this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bug or the forward-slash.  Try adding an extra param at the end that you don't care about or removing the forward-slash

```
http://MYSITE/?r=c/action&token=123456789&t=1

http://MYSITE/?r=caction&token=123456789
```

Comment: I've tried adding additional variable, the variables totally stripped, except the first one,
the forward-slash is required, and I've no problem with it

Answer (score 0):

One option is to put all your needed variables in a single base64 string and pass that guy over as your single querystring parameter.

Pseudo-code would be:

```
data = toBase64String("action&token=123456789")
redirect_uri = "http://MYSITE/?data=" + data;
```

Then you decode it wherever you redirect to.